# Cron Job SQL Check New User

Tags: php, sql, cron

This is more of a is it possible question rather then a technical question.

I've got a tender asking if its possible to check a old user database and if there's new users then add it to the new Joomla User database table.

I thought the best way would be to use a cron job but I don't understand how you would check if there was a new user added to the old database?

Would this be possible and if so what kind of theory would you use?

Thanks

Comment: this sounds hackish... but easy way is adding a table storing a timestamp (yeah, a table with only one row) and comparing that timestamp with the latest user-db entries. If a newer user entry is found then this timestamp during cron run, create new users in your db and updateing that timestamp... but somehow I love the idea to shutdown the database and simply redirect the users directly to the new joomla.

Comment: It was all part of the tender, but they use a in house database that it would be pulled from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765409/adding-php-script-to-cron and google for mysql+select and mysql+insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the Tender has access to both databases and files, i have a question.

Does the old database(website) still in use? I guess so since the user can be incremented!

So why not to edit Joomla files (user related component com_user), to also add the new user to the new database, after the validation/insert on the old one.

This is simple in either cases old 1.5 and newer versions.

Hope i have helped and drove you into the right direction.

Regards.

Comment: Yeah seems like the best way to do it, but the old database wont be a php website more likely a internal system. But thanks anyway :)